# in Jupyter lab, how to jump to last executed cell?

Tags: jupyter-lab

When using jupyter lab, when using run all cells, some cell might have an error so running will stop at that cell. How to jump to this last executed cell in jupyter lab without going through each cell to find it? In VS Code, it is very easy, just click on the button. Does jupyter lab have a similar feature?

Thanks

Comment: anyone know this? Thanks